# jQuery AJAX code does run, but MySQL post does not get deleted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an issue with this code, the full Ajax code runs to the end, and fades out the parent of the deletebtn, here is the code of the deletebtn, post and ajax:

```
    <?php
    include('php/connect.php');
    $roomQuery = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
    $roomResult = mysqli_query($conn, $roomQuery);


    while($roomRow = mysqli_fetch_array($roomResult)){
        echo "<div class='roomParent'>";
        echo "<div class='edit_roomRow'><h1> Rum " . $roomRow['ID'] . "</h1>" . "<h4>" . $roomRow['Description'] . "</h4></div><div name='id' id='removepost' value='" . $roomRow['ID'] . "' class='btn btn-danger delete-btn'>Ta bort</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    mysqli_free_result($roomResult);

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".delete-btn").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var parent = $(this).parent();

    //Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url: "php/deletepost.php",
        data:{ removepost: id },
        success: function(){
        $(this).val("");
        parent.fadeOut("slow")
}});
})
```

And here is the PHP code which the ajax data gets sent to:

```
<?php 
require('connect.php');
$deletesql = "DELETE FROM rooms WHERE ID = " . ($_GET['removepost']);
if(isset($_GET['removepost'])){
    mysqli_query($conn, $deletesql);
}
?>
```

Code is gonna be fixed from sql injections etc. later, this is just testing

Comment: r u really using `$_GET` for deletion?

Comment: I am a real beginner with this, be constructive

Comment: u cant get the value from `<div>`

Comment: you can use data attribute, as `<div name='id' id='removepost' data-value='" . $roomRow['ID'] . "' class='btn btn-danger delete-btn'>Ta bort</div>`

Comment: than you can get the value in jQuery as `$(this).attr("data-value")`

Comment: And yes, i am going to fix it for method: delete instead

Comment: Have you tried to get any error output from your query using `mysqli_error($conn)` or used any network inspector to see what you're actually passing to the script? devpro is right about the JS issue, but debugging the connection would have highlighted this.

Comment: now u have few solutions, try them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, you are trying to access `<div>` attribute as a value in jQuery, you can't get the value of `id` attribute as like that.

**Suggestions:**

1) *You can use data attribute here in your html as:*

```
<div name='id' id='removepost' data-value='" . $roomRow['ID'] . "' class='btn btn-danger delete-btn'>Ta bort</div>
```

2) *Than you need to get values from attribute in jQuery as:*

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-value"); // replace with: var id = $(this).val();
```

3) *In last, very important, use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of direct using the user input, this will help to prevent your code with SQL Injection. If you still want to use `$_GET` method here than note that, everyone can hit the URL with any `removepost`.*

Comment: @DouglasPettersson: glad to help u, dont forgot SQL injection :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$(this).val()`, which will not return anything and certainly not the ID.  Use `$(someElement).attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the value of a div.
I would suggest to change the div to a button instead:

```
echo "<div class='edit_roomRow'><h1> Rum " . $roomRow['ID'] . "</h1>" . "<h4>" . $roomRow['Description'] . "</h4></div><button name='id' id='removepost' value='" . $roomRow['ID'] . "' class='btn btn-danger delete-btn'>Ta bort</button>";
```

Now you can use $(this).val() in your jQuery click event and get the ID value of the room to delete.

A tip if you are new to this is to open up the Developer Console (F12) and type some console.log('item to log') in your jQuery code to see what happens at different steps. If you do this in your current code, and do "console.log(id)", it will output "". (You can also insert breakpoints in your code and step through it to get a better understanding of what happens)

The above tip is not by any means a "professional" or textbook way of handling things, but it does come in handy and people use it more than they care to admit.

**Edit:**

While I haven't used MySQL or PHP in a while, my understanding is that it's best to use PDO with prepared statements.
That way you can prepare statements to re-use, bind parameters to, then execute them and catch any errors.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the data function in jQuery. Just to summarise:

```
<?php $id = $roomRow['ID']; ?>

<div id='removepost'data-id='<?=$id?>' class='btn btn-danger delete-btn'>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(".delete-btn").click(function(){
         var id = $(this).data('id');
     });
</script>
```

Eventually you may want to consider having the SQL code in a separate object, and passing that object into an HTML template view, so you don't have the logic and presentation mixed together.